# Error bars on spectra plotted in a loglog scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting spectra on a loglog scale, the error bars for each data point is the same. I was therefore looking for a way to just plot one error bar in one of the corners of the figure, such as a legend instead of having error bars at each data point.
Is there a easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can plot another point in your plot with the error bar, and use that for the legend. Example:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(30)
plt.plot(x, 'bo')
plt.gca().set_xscale('log')
plt.gca().set_yscale('log')

plt.errorbar([1.3], [53], xerr=[1], yerr=[6], fmt='bo')
plt.text(3.4, 52, 'Typical error')
```

[image]

However, a little word of caution with log plots: the size of your sample error bar will vary on where you put it on the plot! So perhaps it is not the best idea to use the approach of a "typical error bar" in such a plot...